# MongoDB values with undefined script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to make some query from different databases, which I cannot merge them to one `forAll`, the following query probably fails due to `async` call which I cannot manage to solve.

```
var someImageIds = ["111111111111111111"]


use "databaseA"
var transactions = db.transactions.find({"data.transactionImaginaryId": {$in: someImageIds}}) // uses index 
use "databaseB"

transactions.forEach(transaction => { 
      var report = db.reports.find({"metadata.companyId" : parseInt(transaction.data.companyId) , "metadata.originReportId": transaction.data.reportId}).project({}) // uses index
      var expenses = db.expenses.find({"metadata.reportId": report._id}) // uses index
      var assets = db.assets.find({"_id": report.assets[0].imaginaryId}) // uses index
      print(`report with status: ${"report.reportFlow.value"}, ${expenses.count()} expenses, ${assets.count()} assets for ${transaction.data.matchType} transaction _id: ${transaction._id.valueOf()}`)
})
```

The problem is that

```
var report = db.reports.find({"metadata.companyId" : parseInt(transaction.data.companyId) , "metadata.originReportId": transaction.data.reportId}).project({})
```

returns value of `undefined` and I cannot continue with the query since the next line is using this line data.

Any ideas on how to solve that?
I'm using NoSqlBooster v6.2.8, mongo4, and written in NoSqlBooster console.

Thanks!

---

Thanks to @Jeremy Thille I managed to write the following **WORKING** code:

```
var someImageIds = ["111111111111111111"]


use "databaseA"
var transactions = db.transactions.find({"data.transactionImaginaryId": {$in: someImageIds}}) // uses index 
use "databaseB"

transactions.forEach((transaction)=> { 
        const report = await(db.reports.find({ "metadata.companyId": parseInt(transaction.data.companyId), "metadata.originReportId": transaction.data.reportId }).toArray()) // uses index
        const expenses = await(db.expenses.find({ "metadata.reportId": report[0]._id }).toArray()) // uses index
        const assets = await(db.assets.find({ "_id": report[0].assets[0].imaginaryId }).toArray()) // uses index
        print(`report with status: ${report[0].reportFlow.value}, ${expenses.length} expenses, ${assets.length} assets for ${transaction.data.matchType} transaction _id: ${transaction._id.valueOf()}`)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, databases (and HTTP requests, and many other things) are not instantaneous. They need some time to perform an operation. So you need to `await` them, which can't be done in a `.forEach()` loop, but can be in a `for` loop :

```
const someFunctionName = async () => { // needs async

    for (let transaction of transactions) {
        const report = await db.reports.find({ "metadata.companyId": parseInt(transaction.data.companyId), "metadata.originReportId": transaction.data.reportId }).project({}) // uses index
        const expenses = await db.expenses.find({ "metadata.reportId": report._id }) // uses index
        const assets = await db.assets.find({ "_id": report.assets[0].imaginaryId }) // uses index
        
        print(`report with status: ${"report.reportFlow.value"}, ${expenses.count()} expenses, ${assets.count()} assets for ${transaction.data.matchType} transaction _id: ${transaction._id.valueOf()}`)
    }
}
```